# android programmatically add rectangle in

Tags: android

Hello i added rectangle in my canvas now i want to add textview or some other view in that rectangle.Suggest me some tutorial also. Thanks in advance

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.set(20 ,10 ,canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: use canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint)

Comment: @Raghunandan it is not visible

Comment: i do not understand your comment. Not visible?

Comment: @Raghunandan it is not showing on rectangle

Comment: change the color of the paint and try.

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw text on your canvas.

```
        Paint mpaint= new Paint();
        mpaint.setColor(Color.RED);//set red color for rectangle
        mpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);//mpaint will fill the rectangle
        Paint paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);//green color for text
        paint2.setTextSize(30f);//set text size. you can change the stroke width also

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {
   canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 600, 600, mpaint);
   canvas.drawText("hello", 150, 150, paint2);//change x and y according to your needs
     }
```

Resulting snapshot on samsung galaxy s3
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding a View of any kind is out of question here since you are simply drawing on a canvas. But `Canvas.drawText(...)` might be exactly what you are looking for.